# Can we “give kind cooperation”?

Tags: collocation

Is it correct to write the sentence below?

All participants gave good cooperation in the workshop.

Please suggest.

Comment: This is editing. If not, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more common to write:

> All participants cooperated in the workshop.

If you want to express a positive *degree* of cooperation, you could write:

> All participants *fully* cooperated in the workshop.

Alternatively, if you want to express an *ease* of cooperation, you could write:

> All participants cooperated *well* in the workshop.

Using *good* (a normative word) in this case is a bit strange. I will note, however, that in informal speech (not writing) it's fairly common to hear *there was* ***good*** *cooperation*. I just wouldn't use that expression in formal writing outside of dialogue.

---

You can also keep *cooperation* if you add some pronouns:

> All participants gave him their full cooperation.

Comment: Is it ok to use  "give + full cooperation + to someone, something" ?

Comment: @RoseCarter Normally, you need some pronouns. Like *all participants gave him their full cooperation.*